# Does leaving the car on use up fuel?

Tags: pacific-drive

In Pacific Drive, when I put the car in park I can exit the car without turning off the engine. Does leaving the engine turned on use up fuel if the car isn't moving?

Comment: I'm getting the feeling this is interesting for people with *real* cars, as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this article](https://techraptor.net/gaming/guides/pacific-drive-starter):

> Leaving the engine running will drain the fuel, and leaving the lights on (internal and external) will drain the battery.

This makes a lot of sense in a game where decisions like these increase the suspense and demand planning and strategy.

That is, unless you turn on Infinite Fuel in Easy Mode, of course :)

[image: Infinite Fuel option in the Easy Mode tweak menu]